# How to vertically and horizontally center text within a image?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I'm working on a React component using Tailwind CSS, and I'm trying to achieve a specific layout. I have a `div` with an image and two paragraphs inside it. I want the paragraphs to be centered both horizontally and vertically within the `div` so that they appear at the center of the image.

Here's my current code:

```
<div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center text-center">
  <img src="img/slider1.png" alt="slider1" className="mb-4" />
  <p className="font-bold">This paragraph is full of cats</p>
  <p>This paragraph is not.</p>
</div>
```

[image: Output Of Code]

Despite using `items-center` and `justify-center`, the text is not aligning exactly at the center of the image. I want both paragraphs to be positioned at the center, both horizontally and vertically, within the `div`.

Any suggestions or corrections to my current approach would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Paragraphs need to be centered in ***front*** of the image?

Comment: I want to center the paragraphs in the center of the image

Comment: So you have to put the image in background of you're div, don't use img src

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Wrap your image and paragraphs
2. Use absolute positioning for the paragraphs
3. Center the text both horizontally and vertically.

```html
<div className="relative">
  <img src="img/slider1.png" alt="slider1" />
  <div className="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 text-center">
    <p className="font-bold mb-2">This paragraph is full of cats</p>
    <p>This paragraph is not.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Can I add a frame around paragraphs?

Comment: Yes no problem, you can wrap them in a container div and then apply border and padding styles to this container. Tailwind CSS makes this quite straightforward.
-
-
-
<div className="relative">
  <img src="img/slider1.png" alt="slider1" />
  <div className="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 text-center p-4 border border-gray-300 bg-white bg-opacity-75">
    <p className="font-bold mb-2">This paragraph is full of cats</p>
    <p>This paragraph is not.</p>
  </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like this. Use an div to wrap it.

```
<div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen">
  <img src="img/slider1.png" alt="slider1" className="mb-4" />
  <div className="flex flex-col items-center text-center">
    <p className="font-bold">This paragraph</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add `h-screen`to the outer div to ensure that it takes the full height of the viewport.

Also use an additonal `div` to center the paragraphs both horizontally and vertically.